# Key that takes a list of other keys as argument and sets them

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I would like to define a key, let's call it `mystyle`, which has several subkeys, like `mystyle/A` and `mystyle/B`, and I'd like to be able to choose which of these subkeys to set by calling `mystyle=A`, `mystyle=B`, or `mystyle={A,B}`.

That's easy enough if I need to set just one of the subkeys, it can be accomplished using something like this:

```
\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.style=draw,
    mystyle/B/.style={fill=yellow},
    mystyle/.style={
        mystyle/#1
    }
}
```

That allows me to say `\tikz \node [mystyle={B}] {Test};`, and the node will be filled in yellow. However, if I try `\tikz \node [mystyle={A,B}] {Test};`, I get the error `I do not know the key '/tikz/B'`.

I tried defining the keys as follows instead

```
\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.style=draw,
    mystyle/B/.style={fill=yellow},
    mystyle/.style={
        mystyle/.cd,
        #1
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work, because while the change of key directory (`mystyle/.cd`) fixed the problem of pgfkeys not being able to find `mystyle/B`, I now get the following error message: `I do not know the key '/tikz/mystyle/draw'`.

What to do?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.style=draw,
    mystyle/B/.style={fill=yellow},
    mystyle/.style={
        mystyle/.cd,
        #1
    }
}

\tikz \node [mystyle={A,B}] {Test};
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How does a `.style` handler work?
It is basically a `.code` handler (as everything is in the end anyway), the code that is saved is `\pgfkeysalso{#1}`.

The style `A` expands to `\pgfkeysalso{draw}` and `B` to `\pgfkeysalso{fill=yelow}`.

The manual says for `\pgfkeysalso`:

> This command has execatly the same effect as `\pgfkeys`, only the default path is not modified before or after the keys are being set.

The “default path” is the one you’re on currently (with `\tikzset` this is `/tikz`). The `.cd` handler however changes this default path to `/tikz/mystyle`. A key that uses `\pgfkeysalso` then tries to find `draw` and `fill` in this path and fails.

The rather complex handler `.search also` installs a `.unknown` code that tries to use unrecognized keys to apply in the given paths. (In a similar way do `/pgf` keys work in `/tikz`.) [percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3235/percusse) already uses this in his solution and it is probably the most convenient approach.

The problem though is that you must use those keys only in the `/tikz/mystyle` path. You can’t use them in other paths without setting the default path to `/tikz` or `/tikz/mystyle`. For example you can’t do `\pgfkeys{/tikz/mystyle/A}` because as the key is not called from the `/tikz/mystyle` path the installed `.search also` won’t be checked. This may seem as an unrealistic example (and it probably is) but for other styles that do not change the properties of the whole path like for example `insert path` this is important as a key containing such styles may be used anywhere to set exactly those properties.

The most robust way would be to save the styles with `/tikz` (and you know they are used as `/tikz` key and nothing else):

```
\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.style=/tikz/draw,
    mystyle/B/.style={/tikz/fill=yellow}
}
```

If you want the styles to behave as if they would be used in the default `/tikz` path you could use a `.tikz` handler that saves the key as a `\tikzset` (as opposed to a `\pgfkeysalso`). A simple definition like

```
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.tikz/.code=%
  \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\tikzset{#1}}}
```

makes it possible to use it as

```
\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.tikz={draw},
    mystyle/B/.tikz={fill=yellow}}
```

---

In a way, this is also my solution for the `mystyle` switch key.

Again, a `mystyle/.cd` (which also only work if the previous path was `/tikz`) changes the path even for keys you would want to use after `mystyle={A,B}`. While those are most likely again `/tikz` keys they don’t need to be. You could have used `/tikz/mystyle={A,B}` from any PGF keys path without wanting to go back to `/tikz`. Similar to a `.tikz` handler I would define the `mystyle` key as:

```
\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.tikz={draw},
    mystyle/B/.tikz={fill=yellow},
    mystyle/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/mystyle}{#1}
}
```

The manual even says to `\pgfkeysalso` that “[c]hanging the default path inside a `\pgfkeyalso` is dangerous, so use with care”.

---

Similar solutions are used by TikZ naturally, for example the `decoration` key (which is actually a `/pgf` key):

```
\pgfkeys{%
  /pgf/decoration/.code={\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,#1}}}
```

This for example makes it possible to use `decoration={<something>}` from `\pgfset` (e.g. the `/pgf` path) and also from `\tikzset` without the restraint to go back to `/pgf` or `/tikz`. (It would be save though to go back to `/tikz` as `/pgf` is searched from there anyway but for a pure `pgf` solution this would fail.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.tikz/.code=%
  \pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\tikzset{#1}}}

\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.tikz={draw},
    mystyle/B/.tikz={fill=yellow},
    mystyle/.code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/mystyle}{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mystyle={A,B}] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Another solution you might be interested in is the following.

This avoids changing the default path and relies on using `mystyle={…}` when the default path is `/tikz`. You can know say `/.style={</tikz options>}` and use `mystyle={…}` without using an additional handler, the need to specify `/tikz` somehow and somewhere. All it needs is an auxiliary key to use with a `/.list`. (Or you specify the `/.list` in your code directly while using your original definition (`mystyle/.style={mystyle/#1}`): `mystyle/.list={A,B}`.

Though, if you know that the keys you use are TikZ keys, save them as such (with `/.tikz` or `/tikz/`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.style={draw},
    mystyle/B/.style={fill=yellow},
    mystyle/.style={@mystyle/.list={#1}},
    @mystyle/.style={/tikz/mystyle/#1}% auxiliary
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mystyle={A,B}] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, this really clears up a lot of things! The `.list` approach especially will come in very handy. Thank you!

Comment: `\pgfkeys{/tikz/mystyle/A}` shouldn't be used anyway by design. or you explicitly change directory otherwise you will have problems with `insert path` too. For those there is an additional filter mechanism is given. Otherwise that would cause more trouble than it solves.

Answer (score 10):

You can declare alternative locations to look for the unknown keys via `/.search also` handler. This is also done occasionally in `pgfplots` code to collect TikZ based keys for paths (though it has a full-blown `handler config` in action).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    mystyle/A/.style={draw},
    mystyle/B/.style={fill=yellow},
    mystyle/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
    mystyle/.style={
        mystyle/.cd,
        #1,
        /tikz/.cd
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mystyle={A,B}] {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]