# Draw Polygonal Number Using PSTricks (or TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks, automation

I would like to draw the following using PSTricks (or Ti*k*Z):

[image: polygonal-numbers]

(Found on http://i1.wp.com/mathandmultimedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/polygonal-numbers.png.)

I can do it myself using an extremely low-tech soluton where I draw every blue and yellow dot maunally, but I can't figure out how to do it'
automatically'.

P.S. Sorry for not giving it a try myself; I really don't know where to start (other than the fact that is probably has to involve `\multido`s).

**Update**

I would like a representation of the triangle numbers, too.

**Update 2**

Consider the following code (from Qrrbrbirlbel):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.append tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.append code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.prefix tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.prefix code=\tikzset{#1}}
}
\def\polynumset{\pgfqkeys{/polynum}}
\polynumset{
  sides/.initial=4,
  levels/.initial=5,
  side length/.initial=+0.5cm,
  %
  every node/.tikz={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+4pt},
  center node/.tikz={fill=red},
  level nodes/.tikz={fill=blue},
  sublevel nodes/.tikz={fill=yellow},
  %
  every edge/.tikz={draw},
  %
  every corner edge/.code={
    \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
      \ifnum\polynumcorner<\polynumcorners\relax
        \tikzset{draw=none}
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatletter
\def\polynumutil@firstofone#1{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@firstoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@secondoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#2\pgf@stop}
\tikzset{
  polynum/.default=,
  polynum/.style={
    insert path={
      node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/inner nodes/.try, /polynum/center node/.try] (pn@0@1@0) {}
      { [/polynum/.cd,#1]
        [/utils/exec=%
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynumcorners{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/sides}-1}%
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynum@levels{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}}%
          \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\polynum@sidelength{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/side length}}%
          \pgfmathsetmacro\polynum@angle{360/(\the\numexpr\polynumcorners+1\relax)}%
        ]
        \foreach \polynumcorner[evaluate={\polynum@@angle={(\polynumcorner-1)*\polynum@angle}}] in {1,...,\polynumcorners} {
          % get to the next corner,
          % level 1
          ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@sidelength)
            node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, /polynum/level 1 nodes/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0) {}
          % last level
          [/utils/exec={%
            \ifnum\polynumcorner=1\relax
              \expandafter\polynumutil@firstoftwo
            \else
              \expandafter\polynumutil@secondoftwo
            \fi
              {+(\polynum@@angle:\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax*\polynum@sidelength)}
              {   (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynum@levels @0.center)
               ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@levels*\polynum@sidelength)}}]
          % it's only a coordinate because it is used to place everything else
          % including the node at the exact same position
          node[shape=coordinate, alias=pn@\polynumcorner @last] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynum@levels @0) {}
          % all other levels
          \foreach \polynumlevel[count=\polynum@level from 1, evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynum@level/\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax}] in {2,...,\polynum@levels} {
            (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
              edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/level \polynumlevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0) {}
            (pn@\polynumcorner @last.center)
            % the edges between the corner nodes (blue -- blue)
            (pn@\polynumcorner @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax @0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try, /polynum/every corner edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
            % now the sublevels (except for the first corner because it has no previous corner)
            [/utils/exec={%
              \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
                \expandafter\polynumutil@firstofone
              \else
                \expandafter\pgfutil@gobble
              \fi
              {\foreach \polynumsublevel[evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynumsublevel/\polynumlevel}] in {1,...,\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax}{
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                   edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/sublevel nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/sublevel \polynumsublevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel) {}
                 (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                 % the edges between sublevel nodes (blue -- yellow and yellow -- yellow)
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumsublevel-1\relax)
                   edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel)
               }
               % the edge between the last sublevel node and the next corner node (yellow -- blue)
               (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax)
                 edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
               (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
              }}]
          }
          % the edges between corner nodes (level 1, the smallest polygon: red -- blue and blue -- blue)
           (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0)
           (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
        }
        % the last edge (blue -- red)
        (pn@\polynumcorners @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@0@1@0)
      }
    }
  }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\polygonnumbers[1]{%
\foreach \sides in {3,...,#1}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [polynum={/tikz/rotate=360/\sides/2,sides=\sides}];
\foreach \corner in {1,...,\the\numexpr\sides-1\relax}{%
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{pn@\corner@1@0}{center}}
                            {\pgfpointanchor{pn@\corner@\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}@0}{center}}
  \let\angle\pgfmathresult
  \draw[
    blue,
    rotate=\angle,
    rounded corners=1pt,
    thick] (pn@\corner@1@0.\angle+180) ++ (left:2pt) coordinate (@aux)
                                         -- ++ (up:4pt)
                                         -| ([shift=(right:2pt)] pn@\corner@\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}@0.\angle)
                                         |- ([shift=(down:4pt)] @aux)
                                         -- cycle
                                        ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
    \polygonnumbers{6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

How to I create a command where `\polygonnumbers` takes the two arguments `#1 = <number of dots in each row>` and `#2 = <maximal n-gon>`? (Now, I just have a command with the single argument `#1 = <maximal n-gon`>.)

**Update 3**

Unfortunately, I get an error if I change `\polygonnumbers{5}{6}` to `\polygonnumbers{4}{6}` in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.append tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.append code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.prefix tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.prefix code=\tikzset{#1}}
}
\def\polynumset{\pgfqkeys{/polynum}}
\polynumset{
  sides/.initial=4,
  levels/.initial=5,
  side length/.initial=+0.5cm,
  %
  every node/.tikz={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+4pt},
  center node/.tikz={fill=red},
  level nodes/.tikz={fill=blue},
  sublevel nodes/.tikz={fill=yellow},
  %
  every edge/.tikz={draw},
  %
  every corner edge/.code={
    \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
      \ifnum\polynumcorner<\polynumcorners\relax
        \tikzset{draw=none}
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatletter
\def\polynumutil@firstofone#1{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@firstoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@secondoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#2\pgf@stop}
\tikzset{
  polynum/.default=,
  polynum/.style={
    insert path={
      node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/inner nodes/.try, /polynum/center node/.try] (pn@0@1@0) {}
      { [/polynum/.cd,#1]
        [/utils/exec=%
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynumcorners{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/sides}-1}%
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynum@levels{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}}%
          \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\polynum@sidelength{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/side length}}%
          \pgfmathsetmacro\polynum@angle{360/(\the\numexpr\polynumcorners+1\relax)}%
        ]
        \foreach \polynumcorner[evaluate={\polynum@@angle={(\polynumcorner-1)*\polynum@angle}}] in {1,...,\polynumcorners} {
          % get to the next corner,
          % level 1
          ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@sidelength)
            node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, /polynum/level 1 nodes/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0) {}
          % last level
          [/utils/exec={%
            \ifnum\polynumcorner=1\relax
              \expandafter\polynumutil@firstoftwo
            \else
              \expandafter\polynumutil@secondoftwo
            \fi
              {+(\polynum@@angle:\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax*\polynum@sidelength)}
              {   (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynum@levels @0.center)
               ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@levels*\polynum@sidelength)}}]
          % it's only a coordinate because it is used to place everything else
          % including the node at the exact same position
          node[shape=coordinate, alias=pn@\polynumcorner @last] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynum@levels @0) {}
          % all other levels
          \foreach \polynumlevel[count=\polynum@level from 1, evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynum@level/\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax}] in {2,...,\polynum@levels} {
            (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
              edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/level \polynumlevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0) {}
            (pn@\polynumcorner @last.center)
            % the edges between the corner nodes (blue -- blue)
            (pn@\polynumcorner @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax @0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try, /polynum/every corner edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
            % now the sublevels (except for the first corner because it has no previous corner)
            [/utils/exec={%
              \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
                \expandafter\polynumutil@firstofone
              \else
                \expandafter\pgfutil@gobble
              \fi
              {\foreach \polynumsublevel[evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynumsublevel/\polynumlevel}] in {1,...,\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax}{
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                   edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/sublevel nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/sublevel \polynumsublevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel) {}
                 (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                 % the edges between sublevel nodes (blue -- yellow and yellow -- yellow)
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumsublevel-1\relax)
                   edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel)
               }
               % the edge between the last sublevel node and the next corner node (yellow -- blue)
               (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax)
                 edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
               (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
              }}]
          }
          % the edges between corner nodes (level 1, the smallest polygon: red -- blue and blue -- blue)
           (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0)
           (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
        }
        % the last edge (blue -- red)
        (pn@\polynumcorners @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@0@1@0)
      }
    }
  }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\polygonnumbers[2]{%
\foreach \sides in {3,...,#2}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [polynum={/tikz/rotate=360/\sides/2,levels=#1,sides=\sides}];
\foreach \corner in {1,...,\the\numexpr\sides-1\relax}{%
  \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{pn@\corner@1@0}{center}}
                            {\pgfpointanchor{pn@\corner@\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}@0}{center}}
  \let\angle\pgfmathresult
  \draw[
    blue,
    rotate=\angle,
    rounded corners=1pt,
    thick] (pn@\corner@1@0.\angle+180) ++ (left:2pt) coordinate (@aux)
                                         -- ++ (up:4pt)
                                         -| ([shift=(right:2pt)] pn@\corner@\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}@0.\angle)
                                         |- ([shift=(down:4pt)] @aux)
                                         -- cycle
                                        ;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
    \polygonnumbers{4}{6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named pn@1@5@0 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.134     \polygonnumbers{4}{6}
```

**Final**

Here is what I ende up with (after another slight improvement):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[figureposition=bottom]{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{tilpasning}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{%
  font=small,
  labelfont=sc,
  labelsep=tilpasning,
  width=0.7\textwidth
}

\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\tikzset{#1}},
  /handlers/.append tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.append code=\tikzset{#1}},
  /handlers/.prefix tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.prefix code=\tikzset{#1}}
}
\def\polynumset{\pgfqkeys{/polynum}}
\newif\ifpolynumbars
\polynumset{%
  sides/.initial=4,
  levels/.initial=5,
  side length/.initial=+0.5cm,
  x padding/.initial=+2pt,
  y padding/.initial=+2pt,
  bars/.is if=polynumbars,
  every bar/.tikz={draw=blue, thick, rounded corners=+1pt},
  %
  every node/.tikz={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+4pt},
  center node/.tikz={fill=red},
  level nodes/.tikz={fill=blue!60},
  sublevel nodes/.tikz={fill=yellow},
  %
  every edge/.tikz={},
  %
  every corner edge/.code={%
    \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
      \ifnum\polynumcorner<\polynumcorners\relax
        \tikzset{draw=none}
      \fi
    \fi
  }
}
\makeatletter
\def\polynumutil@firstofone#1{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@firstoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@secondoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#2\pgf@stop}
\polynumset{%
  bar path/.style={%
    to path={%
      [/utils/exec=%
         \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart} {center}}
                                   {\pgfpointanchor{\tikztotarget}{center}}
         \let\polynum@a\pgfmathresult
         \pgftransformrotate{\polynum@a}
         \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{center}}
                      {\pgfpointshapeborder{\tikztostart}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{center}}{\pgfpointpolar{90}{1pt}}}}
         \pgfmathveclen{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}
         \edef\polynum@ydistance{\pgfmathresult pt}
         \pgfcoordinate{pn@aux1}
                       {\pgfpointshapeborder
                         {\tikztostart}
                         {\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{center}}
                                      {\pgfpointpolar{180}{1pt}}}}
         \pgfcoordinate{pn@aux2}
                       {\pgfpointshapeborder
                         {\tikztotarget}
                         {\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztotarget}{center}}
                                      {\pgfpointpolar{0}{1pt}}}}
       ]
             ([shift=(left:\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/x padding})]pn@aux1) coordinate (pn@aux)
       -- ++ (up:\polynum@ydistance+\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/y padding})
       -|    ([shift=(right:\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/x padding})] pn@aux2)
       |-    ([shift=(down:\polynum@ydistance+\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/y padding})] pn@aux)
       -- cycle
    }
  }}
\tikzset{%
  polynum/.default=,
  polynum/.style={%
    insert path={%
      node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/inner nodes/.try, /polynum/center node/.try] (pn@0@1@0) {}
      { [/polynum/.cd,#1]
        [/utils/exec=%
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynumcorners{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/sides}-1}
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynum@levels{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}-1}
          \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\polynum@sidelength{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/side length}}
          \pgfmathsetmacro\polynum@angle{360/(\the\numexpr\polynumcorners+1\relax)}
        ]
        \foreach \polynumcorner[evaluate={\polynum@@angle={(\polynumcorner-1)*\polynum@angle}}] in {1,...,\polynumcorners} {%
          % Get to the next corner;
          % level 1
          ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@sidelength)
            node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, /polynum/level 1 nodes/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0) {}
          % last level.
          [/utils/exec={%
            \ifnum\polynumcorner=1\relax
              \expandafter\polynumutil@firstoftwo
            \else
              \expandafter\polynumutil@secondoftwo
            \fi
              {+(\polynum@@angle:\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax*\polynum@sidelength)}
              {   (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynum@levels @0.center)
               ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@levels*\polynum@sidelength)}}]
          % It is only a coordinate because it is used to place everything else,
          % including the node at the exact same position.
          node[shape=coordinate, alias=pn@\polynumcorner @last] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynum@levels @0) {}
          % All other levels
          \foreach \polynumlevel[count=\polynum@level from 1, evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynum@level/\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax}] in {2,...,\polynum@levels} {%
            (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
              edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/level \polynumlevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0) {}
            (pn@\polynumcorner @last.center)
            % The edges between the corner nodes (blue -- blue).
            (pn@\polynumcorner @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax @0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try, /polynum/every corner edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
            % Now the sublevels (except for the first corner because it has no previous corner).
            [/utils/exec={%
              \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
                \expandafter\polynumutil@firstofone
              \else
                \expandafter\pgfutil@gobble
              \fi
              {\foreach \polynumsublevel[evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynumsublevel/\polynumlevel}] in {1,...,\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax}{%
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                   edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/sublevel nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/sublevel \polynumsublevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel) {}
                 (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                 % The edges between sublevel nodes (blue -- yellow and yellow -- yellow).
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumsublevel-1\relax)
                   edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel)
               }
               % The edge between the last sublevel node and the next corner node (yellow -- blue).
               (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax)
                 edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
               (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
              }}]
          }
          % The edges between corner nodes (level 1, the smallest polygon: red -- blue and blue -- blue).
           (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0)
           (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
        }
        % The last edge (blue -- red).
        (pn@\polynumcorners @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@0@1@0)
        % The bars are drawn in an extra loop to make sure they are on top.
        [/utils/exec=%
          \ifpolynumbars\expandafter\polynumutil@firstofone\else\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble\fi
            {\foreach \polynumcorner in {1,...,\polynumcorners} {%
            (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0) edge[/polynum/bar path/.try, /polynum/every bar/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynum@levels @0)}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\polynumset{bars}
\newcommand*\polynum[4][1]{%
  \foreach \sides in {#3,...,#4}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,/polynum/levels=#2]
      \path [/tikz/rotate=360/\sides/2,polynum={sides=\sides}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
 \caption{Illustration of the polygonal numbers~$f_{#3}(#2)$--$f_{#4}(#2)$.}
}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
  \polynum[1.5]{5}{3}{8}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You want this exact representation? [There are others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number).

Comment: @Werner Yes, please. `:)` Then I can also use the intuitive proof on http://mathandmultimedia.com/2012/08/01/polygonal-number-formula/ in my notes. (See also update.)

Comment: When you have a two-argument macro simply do `{1,...,#2}` in the loop and `\path [polynum={/tikz/rotate=360/\sides/2,levels=#1,sides=\sides}];`. Then you can do `\polygonnumbers{5}{6}` which creates diagrams with 3, 4, 5 and 6 corners and 5 levels which is your question’s examples including the triangles.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel See third update. `:(`

Comment: Ah, yes. I see the problem. The `\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}` that draws the blue bars expands to the initial value and not the set value. This can be resolved by setting `/polynum/levels` as an option to the `tikzpicture` (instead of the path) or by implementing the bar-drawing in it. Let me update my answer in a bit which does this (if I get it to work).

Comment: See the update. Your code should work now. (Don’t forget to do `\polynumset{bars}`.)

Comment: Really great! I'll accept your answer even though a PSTricks solution might appear. `:)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a solution using TikZ.

There exist a few keys that change the graphics parameter:

- `sides`: the number of sides/corners in the polygon;
- `level`: the number of repetitions of the polygon;
- `side length`: the length of one side of the polygon;
- for the “bars”:

  - `x padding` and
  - `y padding` as well as
  - the switch `bars` that can be used to turn off/on the drawing of the bars.

The polygon is drawn with the `center node` at the point where the path currently is where you use the `polynum` key. The “polynum” can be rotated by rotating the path.
The polygons stand on their center corner if you rotate the path about `360/<corners>/2`.

The bar is drawn with an active rotation in mind (that is the reason for the `\pgfpointshapeborder`), this makes it possible to include the nodes as they are without the need to rotate them or to use `transform shape`. The bar-drawing algorithm though will create a bad result if the nodes are not of the same size.

The macros

- `\polynumcorner`,
- `\polynumlevel`,
- `\polynumsublevel` and
- `\polynumcorners` (i.e. the total number of corners)

can be used to affect the styles, this is used inside the `every corner edge` style (actually a `.code` key) that turns the drawing of the edge between certain corner nodes explicitly off.

The nodes are named: `pn@<corner>@<level>@<sublevel>`. The red center node is named `pn@0@1@0`, it is the only 0th corner node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,png={size=315,density=600},convert=false]{standalone}
\pgfkeys{% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125700/16595
  /handlers/.tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.append tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.append code=\tikzset{#1}},%
  /handlers/.prefix tikz/.code=\pgfkeys{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.prefix code=\tikzset{#1}}}
\def\polynumset{\pgfqkeys{/polynum}}
\newif\ifpolynumbars
\polynumset{
  sides/.initial=4,
  levels/.initial=5,
  side length/.initial=+.5cm,
  x padding/.initial=+2pt,
  y padding/.initial=+2pt,
  bars/.is if=polynumbars,
  every bar/.tikz={draw=blue, thick, rounded corners=+1pt},
  %
  every node/.tikz={shape=circle,draw,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+4pt},
  center node/.tikz={fill=red},
  level nodes/.tikz={fill=blue},
  sublevel nodes/.tikz={fill=yellow},
  %
  every edge/.tikz={},
  %
  every corner edge/.code={
    \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
      \ifnum\polynumcorner<\polynumcorners\relax
        \tikzset{draw=none}
      \fi
    \fi
  },
}
\makeatletter
\def\polynumutil@firstofone#1{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@firstoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#1\pgf@stop}
\def\polynumutil@secondoftwo#1#2{\tikz@scan@next@command#2\pgf@stop}
\polynumset{
  bar path/.style={
    to path={
      [/utils/exec=%
         \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart} {center}}
                                   {\pgfpointanchor{\tikztotarget}{center}}%
         \let\polynum@a\pgfmathresult
         \pgftransformrotate{\polynum@a}%
         \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{center}}
                      {\pgfpointshapeborder{\tikztostart}{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{center}}{\pgfpointpolar{90}{1pt}}}}%
         \pgfmathveclen{\pgf@x}{\pgf@y}%
         \edef\polynum@ydistance{\pgfmathresult pt}%
         \pgfcoordinate{pn@aux1}
                       {\pgfpointshapeborder
                         {\tikztostart}
                         {\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztostart}{center}}
                                      {\pgfpointpolar{180}{1pt}}}}%
         \pgfcoordinate{pn@aux2}
                       {\pgfpointshapeborder
                         {\tikztotarget}
                         {\pgfpointadd{\pgfpointanchor{\tikztotarget}{center}}
                                      {\pgfpointpolar{0}{1pt}}}}%
       ]
             ([shift=(left:\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/x padding})]pn@aux1) coordinate (pn@aux)
       -- ++ (up:\polynum@ydistance+\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/y padding})
       -|    ([shift=(right:\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/x padding})] pn@aux2)
       |-    ([shift=(down:\polynum@ydistance+\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/y padding})] pn@aux)
       -- cycle
    }
  }}
\tikzset{
  polynum/.default=,
  polynum/.style={
    insert path={
      node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/inner nodes/.try, /polynum/center node/.try] (pn@0@1@0) {}
      { [/polynum/.cd,#1]
        [/utils/exec=%
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynumcorners{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/sides}-1}%
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro\polynum@levels{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}}%
          \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\polynum@sidelength{\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/side length}}%
          \pgfmathsetmacro\polynum@angle{360/(\the\numexpr\polynumcorners+1\relax)}%
        ]
        \foreach \polynumcorner[evaluate={\polynum@@angle={(\polynumcorner-1)*\polynum@angle}}] in {1,...,\polynumcorners} {
          % get to the next corner,
          % level 1
          ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@sidelength)
            node[/polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, /polynum/level 1 nodes/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0) {}
          % last level
          [/utils/exec={%
            \ifnum\polynumcorner=1\relax
              \expandafter\polynumutil@firstoftwo
            \else
              \expandafter\polynumutil@secondoftwo
            \fi
              {+(\polynum@@angle:\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax*\polynum@sidelength)}
              {   (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynum@levels @0.center)
               ++ (\polynum@@angle:\polynum@levels*\polynum@sidelength)}}]
          % it's only a coordinate because it is used to place everything else
          % including the node at the exact same position
          node[shape=coordinate, alias=pn@\polynumcorner @last] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynum@levels @0) {}
          % all other levels
          \foreach \polynumlevel[count=\polynum@level from 1, evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynum@level/\the\numexpr\polynum@levels-1\relax}] in {2,...,\polynum@levels} {
            (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
              edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/level nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/level \polynumlevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0) {}
            (pn@\polynumcorner @last.center)
            % the edges between the corner nodes (blue -- blue)
            (pn@\polynumcorner @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax @0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try, /polynum/every corner edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
            % now the sublevels (except for the first corner because it has no previous corner)
            [/utils/exec={%
              \ifnum\polynumcorner>1\relax
                \expandafter\polynumutil@firstofone
              \else
                \expandafter\pgfutil@gobble
              \fi
              {\foreach \polynumsublevel[evaluate={\polynum@pos=\polynumsublevel/\polynumlevel}] in {1,...,\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax}{
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                   edge[draw=none] node[pos=\polynum@pos, /polynum/every node/.try, /polynum/sublevel nodes/.try, style/.expanded={/polynum/sublevel \polynumsublevel\space nodes/.try}] (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel) {}
                 (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0.center)
                 % the edges between sublevel nodes (blue -- yellow and yellow -- yellow)
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumsublevel-1\relax)
                   edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
                 (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\polynumsublevel)
               }
               % the edge between the last sublevel node and the next corner node (yellow -- blue)
               (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @\polynumlevel @\the\numexpr\polynumlevel-1\relax)
                 edge[/polynum/every edge/.try]
               (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynumlevel @0)
              }}]
          }
          % the edges between corner nodes (level 1, the smallest polygon: red -- blue and blue -- blue)
           (pn@\the\numexpr\polynumcorner-1\relax @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0)
           (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0.center)
        }
        % the last edge (blue -- red)
        (pn@\polynumcorners @1@0) edge[/polynum/every edge/.try] (pn@0@1@0)
        % the bars are drawn in an extra loop to make sure they are on top
        [/utils/exec=%
          \ifpolynumbars\expandafter\polynumutil@firstofone\else\expandafter\pgfutil@gobble\fi
            {\foreach \polynumcorner in {1,...,\polynumcorners} {
            (pn@\polynumcorner @1@0) edge[/polynum/bar path/.try, /polynum/every bar/.try] (pn@\polynumcorner @\polynum@levels @0)}}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\polynumset{bars}
\begin{document}
\foreach \sides in {3,...,6}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[/polynum/levels=3]
\path [polynum={/tikz/rotate=360/\sides/2,sides=\sides}];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\foreach \level in {2,...,5,5,4,3,2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [polynum={levels=\level}];
\useasboundingbox (-8pt,-8pt) rectangle (2.5cm+8pt,2.5cm+8pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image][image][image][image][image: Picture for <code>sides=7</code>][image]

Comment: Really nice. Any change I can make you (1) draw the bars around the blue dots and (2) connect the dots as on the picture, too?

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to control the distance between the triangle figure and the square figure and so on; not bewteen the individual triangles and so on.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I have updated my answer with a revised version of the `polynum` key. The loops are now more efficient. The edges are all drawn with the `every edge` style. The edges in the blue bars also use the style `every corner edge` where it is checked whether it is the first or the last corner. One could add similar to the nodes edge styles for different corners/levels/sublevels. But it doesn’t look like that is needed so I left it out. Can you elaborate on your last comment? The only length input is the `side length`. Everything else is up to you: placement, position, rotation.

Comment: Seriously nice! Never mind the last comment. `;)` Assume I want to change `levels/.initial` to something != 5. Can the length of the bars be set automatically to the value of `levels/.initial`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Simply use the `levels` key with another integer, e.g. `levels=3` (the code breaks for levels lower than `2`, one need a few more `if`s if this should be possible, too). The value of the `levels` key can be accessed with `\pgfkeysvalueof{/polynum/levels}` which I have done in the process of the bar drawing.

Comment: I have made a second update to the question; can you maybe help with this? `:)`

Comment: @texenthusiast Okay; sorry. I'll do that from now on.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

This solution is based on the object-oriented feature of the `Asymptote`.
The basic structure `struct PolygonalNumber` is defined in `asydef` environment,
and can be used later in `asy` pictures to create and draw objects of this kind.
For example, a triangular object named `P3` with 5 layers is defined as
`PolygonalNumber P3=PolygonalNumber(3,5);` and command `draw(P3);` will draw it. 
`PolygonalNumber` objects can be transformed as usual, for example
`draw(shift(6,0)*P4);` draws a `P4` object shifted to the right. Or they can be used
directly in the `draw` commands: the code to produce the image above was just

```
size(400);
for(int i=3;i<=7;++i){
  draw(shift((i-3)*(5+i-3),0)*PolygonalNumber(i,5));
};
```

A complete MWE `polynum.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
struct PolygonalNumber{
  int n,m;
  real unitStep;
  real boxW;
  transform t;
  pair O=(0,0);
  pair[][] dots;

  pen originPen=red;
  pen sideLinePen=darkblue;
  pen cornerDotPen=blue;
  pen sideDotPen=orange;
  pen boxPen=blue;

  void drawSides(){
    guide g; 
    pair center,p;
    pair[] skin;    
    for(int i=1;i<=m;++i){
      p=(i*unitStep,0);
      g=O;
      center=i*unitStep/2*(1,1/Tan(180/n));
      for(int j=0;j<n-1;++j){
        g=g--(rotate(j*360.0/n,center)*p);
      }
      g=g--cycle;
      draw(t*g,sideLinePen);
      skin=new pair[];      
      for(int j=0;j<size(g);++j){
        skin.push(point(g,j));  
      }
      dots.push(skin);
    }
  }

  void drawCornerDots(){
    for(int i=0;i<dots.length;++i){
      for(int j=1;j<dots[i].length;++j){
        dot(t*dots[i][j],cornerDotPen);
      }
    }
  }

  void drawSideDots(){
    pair p,q;
    real s;
    for(int i=1;i<dots.length;++i){
      for(int j=1;j<dots[i].length-1;++j){
        p=dots[i][j];
        q=dots[i][j+1];
        for(int k=1;k<i+1;++k){
          s=k/(i+1);
          dot(t*(p*(1-s)+q*s),sideDotPen);
        }  
      }
    }
  }

  void drawOriginDots(){
    for(int i=0;i<dots.length;++i){
      dot(t*O,originPen);      
    }    
  }

  guide buildBox(pair a, pair b){
    pair d,p,q,ds;
    d=dir(b-a);
    ds=boxW*d;
    p=a-ds; q=b+ds; 
    guide[] g=strokepath(p--q,red+boxW);
    return g[0];
  }

  void drawBoxes(){
    pair a,b;
    for(int j=1;j<n;++j){
      a=dots[0][j];
      b=dots[m-1][j];
      draw(t*buildBox(a,b),boxPen);      
    }
  }

  void draw(){
    drawSides();
    drawCornerDots();
    drawSideDots();
    drawOriginDots();
    drawBoxes();
  }

  void operator init(int n=3,int m=6,real unitStep=1,transform t=identity(),real boxW=0.4){
    assert(n>2 && m>0);
    this.n=n; this.m=m; 
    this.unitStep=unitStep;
    this.boxW=boxW;
    this.t=t;
  }
}
PolygonalNumber operator*(transform t=identity(),PolygonalNumber p){p.t=t; return p;}; 
void draw(PolygonalNumber p){p.draw();};
\end{asydef}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(400);
for(int i=3;i<=7;++i){
  draw(shift((i-3)*(5+i-3),0)*PolygonalNumber(i,5));
};
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf polynum.tex`.

Answer (score 10):

I started with this but then I got bored :) Always nice to steal Jake's `ncbar`from [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command)

`\numofsides` and `\numofiters` define the polygon shape and how many times it is repeated. I don't have Qrrbrbirlbel's patience. So it's just for fun.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={to path=(\tikztostart)--($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)},
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
bluedot/.style={circle,fill=blue,draw,inner sep=0,minimum size=3pt,anchor=center},
yellowdot/.style={bluedot,fill=yellow},
]
\def\numofsides{10} %Change these
\def\numofiters{10} %Change these
\foreach \x in {1,...,\numofiters}{
\begin{scope}[on background layer]\node[rotate={floor(\numofsides/2)*360/\numofsides}, 
      inner sep=0,anchor=corner 1,
      draw,minimum size=\x*8mm,
      blue,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=\numofsides] (n\x) {};\end{scope}
    \foreach \y[count=\yi,count=\yj from 0,remember=\y as \lasty] in {corner 2,corner 3,corner ...,corner \numofsides} {
    \node[bluedot,rotate={((1-(1-(2/\numofsides)))*90)*\yj-90}] (n\x c\yi) at (n\x.\y) {};
    \ifnum\x>1\ifnum\yi>1\foreach\z in{1,...,\numexpr\x-1\relax}{
        \node[yellowdot] at ($(n\x.\lasty)!\z/\x!(n\x.\y)$){};}\fi\fi
    }
}
\foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {1,...,\numexpr\numofsides-1}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\myangle{((1-(1-(2/\numofsides)))*90)*\xi+180}
\draw[rounded corners=1pt,blue] ([shift={(\myangle:1pt)}]n1c\x.south) to[ncbar=2pt] 
                           ([shift={(\myangle:-1pt)}]n\numofiters c\x.north) to[ncbar=2pt]
                           ([shift={(\myangle:1pt)}]n1c\x.south);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A truly ridiculous image

[image]

With `\def\numofsides{24}` and `\def\numofiters{24}`:

[image: output]

Awesome! `:)`

Comment: Dammit, I forgot the red node at the corner.

Comment: Nice drawing! `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Try 20,20 it gets weirder :)

Comment: See update to your post. `:)`

Comment: Come to think of it; can I make you draw the red dot too? Your example is useful if only a single type of number is required.

Comment: Come to think of it (again), I can still use Qrrbrbirlbel's code so never mind.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I can make it but I didn't wrap this into a new command which you can do yourself by putting everything inside a newcommand using `#1`,`#2`. So I was hoping that part is solved.