# TeX capacity exceeded with \pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys, tcolorbox

I'm trying to create a code listing and set custom options using `pgfkeys`. The below provided code works fine. The style handler for title option (currently commented out) is breaking TeX compilation by throwing the `capacity exceeded` error. What is wrong with the title style handler ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\pgfkeys{%
  /code listing/.cd,%
  title/.initial = {},%
  label/.initial = {},%
  %% title/.style = \pgfkeys{%
  %%   /tcb/.cd,%
  %%   title=#1,%
  %% }%
}

\newtcbinputlisting{\CodeListing}[2][]{%
  beamer, breakable, listing only,%
  colback=red!5!white, fonttitle=\ttfamily,%
  listing file=#2%
}

\newcommand{\IncludeCodeFromFile}[2][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/code listing}{#1}%
  \CodeListing{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\IncludeCodeFromFile[title=Some Code]{somefile.cxx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like \pgfkeys inside \pgfkeys is giving problem. I've removed the \pgfkeys inside style handler and it is working now.

Comment: Yes, a `.style` key collects other styles, a `.code` key would be the right choice for a key with `\pgfkeys`. What are you trying to do, though? You first define a value key `title` and then overwrite it with `title/.style`. — Anyway, it would be better to do `title/.style={/tcb/title={#1}}`, see [Key that takes a list of other keys as argument and sets them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125676)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just cut out the `\pgfkeys` call within the `.style` and leave only the list of keys that was in its argument.  Note that the `.style` handler is a kind of `.code`, one that implicitly passes its argument to `\pgfkeysalso`.  Basically, it's a `\pgfkeys` macro that "expands" to the keys you give it.