# Global definition of pgfplots axes style conflicts with colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I am trying to plot an individual colorbar (with no axis), using the code below (MWE):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            hide axis,
            scale only axis,
            colorbar,
            point meta min=0,
            point meta max=1,
            colorbar style={height=5cm}]
            \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It works perfectly, but if I add the following options into my preamble:

```
\pgfplotsset{every linear axis/.append style={
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={\,},
}}
```

the compiling fails, giving that error message:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/pgf/number
format/xshift', to  which you passed '0.3cm', and I am going to ignore
it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Since I do need those options for other plots, how can I get rid of this error? And how can I define the formatting options for the colorbar ticks?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: Qrrbrbirlbel's answer to [Key that takes a list of other keys as argument and sets them](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125676/key-that-takes-a-list-of-other-keys-as-argument-and-sets-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and probably the most reliable solution is spelling out the path explicitly without changing the key family.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\pgfplotsset{every linear axis/.append style={
    /pgf/number format/use comma,
    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={\,},
  }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            hide axis,
            scale only axis,
            colorbar,
            point meta min=0,
            point meta max=1,
            colorbar style={height=5cm}]
            %\addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Otherwise you have a few options, such setting the keys in a `/.code` handler or any of the solutions linked in Jake's comment etc.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you, and sorry for the delay!